# How to add popup/bubble?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I tryed make demo chrome extension. Logic:
Extension gets selected text (after context menu click) and show it in a popup window, like this (TmTranslator img for example):
[image]

My code:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({ //add context menu 
    id: "myContextMenu",
    title: "Get Text",
    contexts:["selection"],
    onclick: createPopup
});
function createPopup(info){ 
    var selText = info.selectionText; //Get selected text
    //Now, how to add bubble with selected text???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the background page is notified about the context-menu event and the DOM you want to manipulate is that of the web-page, you'll need to have the background-page inject some code into the corresponding tab, e.g. using **[`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript)**. E.g.:

```
function createPopup(info){ 
    var selText = info.selectionText; //Get selected text
    //Now, how to add bubble with selected text???
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: 'alert("' + selText + '");'
    });
}
```

<sub>Your injected code or file would be more complex of course, but you get the idea.</sub>

---

Things to keep in mind:

- In order to be able to inject code into a web-page, you need to declare the appropriate **[host match pattern](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html)** in your `permissions` section in manifest.
- If the interaction with the web-page is frequent, it might be preferrable to inject a **[content-script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)** once and then communicate with it using **[Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)**.